# Width of elements in a menu bar consisting of lists

Tags: html, css

I got a menu bar on my website which is consisting of lists. The html looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul class="menu">
   <li class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">HOME</a></li>
   <li class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">MOSAIC</a></li>
   <li class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">SUCCESS</a></li>
   <li class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
   <li class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the css looks like this:

```
#menu {
    margin-left: 10%;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    left:0;
    width:80%;
    height:2.2em;
    background:#576361;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}

ul.menu {
    float:middle;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style-type:none;
}

a.menu {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:1.8em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:#576361;
    padding:0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    border-left:1px solid white;
}
```

And my menubar looks like following at the moment:

[image]

It just takes 80% of the sites width, but the 5 elements doesn't take 20% of the 80% as expected. How can I fix my issue ? It would be also pretty awesome if you could explain to me how the correct answer is working if it is not obvious and self explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any borders or padding will **add** to the width of the elements until you tell them not to with

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCjVM/1/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    width:80%;
    height:2.2em;
    background:#576361;
    overflow:hidden;}

ul.menu {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style-type:none;
}

a.menu {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:1.8em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:#576361;
    padding:0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    border-left:1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: I think this one is cleaner

Comment: It's a broad as it's long. Mine fixes it with one property addition (which is basically something one should consider for all sites). Alex's is a perfectly acceptable solution though.

Comment: Sure, box-sizing is a very important thing for each site. But this solution still uses float: middle and is really messed up. But you're right it's the fastet fix for that code.

Comment: Float middle is just a copy of the original code. Since it's invalid CSS it's just ignored..but, for you,I'll remove it.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is to use `table-cell` and apply the style in `li` element not in children ones like this:

```
#menu {    
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    left:0;
    width:80%;
    height:2.2em;
    background:#576361;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.menu {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul{
    display:table;
}

li{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    width:20%;
    height:1.8em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    background-color:#576361;
    padding:0.2em 0.6em;
    border-left:1px solid white;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8tbP/7/)

Comment: The ul.menu won't be 80% of the page, will it? In my opinion it won't because it's parent has position: absolute. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are using borders.
Borders add 2px to every element.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Is the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/Hc3au/

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the position of #menu to relative or add an wrapper containing the list. I'm also pretty sure there is no float: middle, just right and left ( and none and inherit ).

Also I do prefer the following:

```
    ul.menu > li 
    { 
       width: 20%; 
    }

    ul.menu > li > a 
    {
       width: 100%;
    }
```

Why do you use the menu class on every element?